# Who is this character in X-Men: The Last Stand? What is his power?

Tags: character, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-the-last-stand

After watching *X-Men: The Last Stand* again, I wanted to know more about this character. Who is he?

[image]

We see him growing bones out of his wrists and throwing them. Does his power only consist of generating bones?

It looks like he can also heal, but is it just the area where the bone exits the flesh? Does he have some kind of enhanced accuracy or is it just practice?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

His name is Spike. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spike_(Marvel_Comics)):

> In the movie X-Men: The Last Stand, a "Spike" character portrayed by Lance Gibson appeared in a battle with Wolverine, where he was depicted with the ability to extrude bony spikes from his flesh and hurl them with great speed and force. The battle culminates in a mutual stabbing.

His powers are not explored much in the film. He can create spikes out of his bones, but he doesn't seem to have the power of healing, otherwise he would probably have survived.

Don't confuse him with [Spyke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spyke), who has a similar kind of power with some extensions and limited to the *X-Men: Evolution* animated series,  except for an *X-Babies* cameo.

Comment: oh ! thanks about the character identification. I will look at his powers in detail

Comment: Reminds me of Marrow from 90s comics, any confirmed link between the two?

Comment: @G.James No idea about it

Comment: Reminds me of Spike from Tom and Jerry cartoons :)

Comment: Considering the characterization differences between other background characters, that Spike is likely meant to be Spyke...

Comment: @g.james well,  marrow isn't the only mutant with bone growths. But then again, she's female, and this character is a black male like Spyke.

Comment: @cde but if I am not wrong then  Spyke came later then comics spike.

Comment: You are :). Y was 2000. X - Static Spike was 2001. New Mutant Spike was 2002. Then this spike was what, 2005? They are all really the same character.

Comment: @cde to me all of them are bleh except  Spyke from X-Men evolution .

Answer (score 8):

His name is [Spike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spike_(Marvel_Comics)).

> He is a mutant that could generate razor-sharp spikes from his body, which he could fire outward with deadly accuracy.

It was played by [Lance Gibson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lance_Gibson)

> a mutant who battles Wolverine in the forest by extruding bony spikes from his flesh - the character was added because the editing team felt that the original cut of the scene portrayed Logan as a cold-blooded killer, which could be changed if another mutant attacked Wolverine before he struck the Brotherhood